# error jest-worker just run in cpanel (adonisjs + nextjs + reactjs)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, cpanel, adonis.js

hello i got problem when deploying adonisjs + nextjs + reactjs in cpanel. i got the log error like this

```
events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn /opt/alt/alt-nodejs12/root/usr/bin/node EAGAIN
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'EAGAIN',
  code: 'EAGAIN',
  syscall: 'spawn /opt/alt/alt-nodejs12/root/usr/bin/node',
  path: '/opt/alt/alt-nodejs12/root/usr/bin/node',
  spawnargs: [
    '/home/test123/nodevenv/repositories/testproject/12/lib/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js'
  ]
}
```

**my server.js**

```
'use strict'

const { Ignitor } = require('@adonisjs/ignitor')

new Ignitor(require('@adonisjs/fold'))
  .appRoot(__dirname)
  .fireHttpServer()
  .catch(console.error)
```

**my next.config.js**

```
'use strict'

const next = require('next')
const { withPlugins } = require('next-compose-plugins')
const withOffline = require('next-offline')
require('dotenv').config()

const nextWithOfflineConfig = {
    dontAutoRegisterSw: false,
    generateInDevMode: false,
    workboxOpts: {
        swDest: './next/.next/service-worker.js',
        runtimeCaching: [
            {
                urlPattern: /^https?.*/,
                handler: 'NetworkFirst',
                options: {
                    cacheName: 'https-calls',
                    networkTimeoutSeconds: 15,
                    expiration: {
                        maxEntries: 150,
                        maxAgeSeconds: 1 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 1 day
                    },
                    cacheableResponse: {
                        statuses: [0, 200],
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
        debug: false,
    },
}


const nextEnv = {
    env: {
        APP_KEY: process.env.APP_KEY,
    }
}


module.exports = withPlugins([
    [withOffline, { nextWithOfflineConfig }],
    [nextEnv]
])
```

**package.json**

```
"next": "^10.0.9",
"next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.1",
"next-offline": "^5.0.3",
"next-page-transitions": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
"next-pwa": "^5.2.21",
"react": "^17.0.2",
```

**cpanel dependencies**

```
node 12.22.9
npm 6.14.0
```

**i already try**

rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install

but still not solve the issue

any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess your server is running CloudLinux, as this is when this error usually comes up?

It's down to the limits on the number of processes and threads you can create inside an LVE.  If you edit your next.conf.js and add the experimental section:

```
module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    workerThreads: false,
    cpus: 4
  }
};
```

This disables worker threads, and sets a CPU count of 4 so it limits the processes created - you might still need to adjust this depending on the limits inside the account you're running the build from.

You can read a bit more about it here in the blog I wrote after helping a customer with the same issue: https://kdaws.com/2022/10/fixing-next-js-error-spawn-errno-11-on-cpanel-and-plesk-with-cloudlinux/

Thanks,

Karl